# Combine multiline log messages without timestamp into one line in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a log file which is in the following format.

```
Wed Feb 21 00:59:32 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
     '----action----tansfer'
     '----failed----'
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
   <Error occurred at line 44>
<html>
.....
....
....
</html>
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
```

I need to format log in the following format so that I can apply some downsteam text processing logic.

```
Wed Feb 21 00:59:32 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message '----action----tansfer' '----failed----'
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message <Error occurred at line 44> <html>.... ..... ....</html>
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
```

Is it possible to get log message in this format. I'm thinking of something like - if the new line character is not followed by a date regex then replace with space character, but couldn't quite construct the regex.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will read the log file and then write it back into the out.txt file in your desired format. I used re for this task with negative lookahead for Wed in the next line

```
import re
with open('log.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = f.read()

a = re.sub(r'\n(?!Wed)', '', a)

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(a)
```

Output:

```
Wed Feb 21 00:59:32 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message     '----action----tansfer'     '----failed----'
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message   <Error occurred at line 44><html>.............</html>
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
```

Comment: Thanks @mamun, I slightly modified your regex to find the complete datetime instead of  "Wed" and I'm using following regex and its working for me.
`\n(?!([a-zA-Z]{3}\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\d{4}))`

Answer (score 0):

This regex string looks like what you need:

```
'.*\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\ \d{4}.*'
```

It tries to match for this:

```
00:59:33 2018 # Any number works as long as it's this format
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my non-regex approach:

```
with open("./t.txt") as read_file: #Current Log file
    with open("./fix_t.txt", 'w') as write_file: #A new log file
        data = False
        for line in read_file:
            if "message" in line:
                if data: write_file.write(data + "\n")
                data = line.strip("\n")
            else:
                data += line.strip("\n")
        if data: write_file.write(data + "\n")
```

Result in new log file:

```
Wed Feb 21 00:59:32 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message     '----action----tansfer'     '----failed----'
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message   <Error occurred at line 44><html>.............</html>
Wed Feb 21 00:59:33 2018 XXXXXX.x1:00000: message
```